# Apache Cordova Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio, gradle, cordova-cli

After some updates to Android Studio and Apache Cordova my Apache Cordova project is not building.

I am new to Apache Cordova, OS X and Android Studio.

In Android Studio when I Rebuild Project I get the following error in the Gradle console.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED
```

In the terminal when I run the command `cordova --version` it prints out `4.0.0` and `which javac` prints out `/usr/bin/javac` but echo $JAVA_HOME prints nothing (an empty line).

*UPDATE: I am setting the path of JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME in the terminal even though I get the same errors as shown below and after closing the terminal the JAVA_HOME and ANDROID_HOME environment variables are lost, I set them as `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_51.jdk/Contents/Home` and `export ANDROID_HOME=/Users/apple/Library/Android/sdk`*

When I try to build the project from Cordova CLI also it is not working.

I get the following errors, where as if I create a new project after changing the distributionUrl in gradle-wrapper.properties and changing the buildToolsVersion from "19.0.0" to "19.1.0" the new project worked fine.

Please help.

cordova compile command

```
Sreekanth-2:19:02:16 Sreekanth$ cordova compile
Running command: "/Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:02:16/platforms/android/cordova/build" 
Buildfile: /Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:02:16/platforms/android/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:/Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:02:16/platforms/android/build.xml:7: The following error occurred while executing this line:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7/libexec/lib/ant.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:212)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:256)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseUnknownElement(ProjectHelper2.java:131)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseAntlibDescriptor(ProjectHelper2.java:111)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Antlib.createAntlib(Antlib.java:94)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.loadAntlib(Definer.java:425)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:277)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.checkNamespace(ComponentHelper.java:874)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.getDefinition(ComponentHelper.java:307)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:263)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:430)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:164)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:93)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:829)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)

Total time: 0 seconds

/Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:02:16/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:02:16/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:02:16/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
```

cordova build command

```
Sreekanth-2:19:02:16 Sreekanth$ cordova build
Running command: "/Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:02:16/platforms/android/cordova/build" 
Buildfile: /Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:02:16/platforms/android/build.xml

BUILD FAILED
/Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:/Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:02:16/platforms/android/build.xml:7: The following error occurred while executing this line:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:/usr/local/Cellar/ant/1.9.7/libexec/lib/ant.jar (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open0(Native Method)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(RandomAccessFile.java:316)
    at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:243)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:212)
    at org.apache.tools.zip.ZipFile.<init>(ZipFile.java:177)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:256)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseUnknownElement(ProjectHelper2.java:131)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parseAntlibDescriptor(ProjectHelper2.java:111)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Antlib.createAntlib(Antlib.java:94)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.loadAntlib(Definer.java:425)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Definer.execute(Definer.java:277)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.checkNamespace(ComponentHelper.java:874)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.getDefinition(ComponentHelper.java:307)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:284)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ComponentHelper.createComponent(ComponentHelper.java:263)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.makeObject(UnknownElement.java:430)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.maybeConfigure(UnknownElement.java:164)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:347)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.ProjectHelper2.parse(ProjectHelper2.java:180)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.configureProject(ProjectHelper.java:93)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:829)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:236)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:285)
    at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:112)

Total time: 0 seconds

/Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:02:16/platforms/android/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error code 1 for command: ant with args: debug,-f,/Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:02:16/platforms/android/build.xml,-Dout.dir=ant-build,-Dgen.absolute.dir=ant-gen
Error: /Users/apple/Desktop/Sreekanth/Togetherly Daily Work/19:02:16/platforms/android/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 1
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:110:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:1015:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:1087:5)
Sreekanth-2:19:02:16 Sreekanth$
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to Project.Properties

add the following lines

```
cordova.system.library.1=com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:9.8.0
cordova.system.library.2=com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:9.8.0
```

run the cordova commands again, You can able to build a release and debug builds

Answer (score -1):

Type the following in your terminal

echo "export JAVA_HOME=`/usr/libexec/java_home`"

This will print the exact export for Java_home , copy that and paste it in terminal and press enter.

Then try echo $java_home.

Comment: Why is the error actually happening? How should your suggestion help?

Comment: And $(command) syntax is used for command substitution, that is /usr/libexec/java_home will be executed and its output assigned to JAVA_HOME.

Comment: I too had this issue with java home and it helped me